# Stream live audio data (from line-in) with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, http, streaming

I want to stream live recorded audio via a HTTP stream from the Mac's line in. When searching for this problem I found a lot of tutorials about how to receive a stream, but nothing about sending a stream.

Is there any tutorial about sending a stream which does not base on a static local file? I found some information on CocoaHTTPServer, but I believe this server can only stream static files. I am right?